# Do we need to create raw transaction for every UTXO that we use during a transaction?

Tags: transactions, raw-transaction, bitcoin

Let say I have 2 UTXOs, one has  value = 0.0001 and another one has value = 0.00005. Now I want to send 0.00014. SO now I have to use both UTXO to perform transaction. So do I have to create 2 raw transaction in order to perform this transaction or one raw transaction? If one transaction, then which txid we will use?

Answer (score 1):

Ethereum does not have a concept of UTXOs - there are only balances. So once an address receives Ethers it is added to its balance and any amount can be sent out (which is smaller or equal to the current balance). So you can use one transaction to send any amount of Ether out of an account.

Comment: Yes but actually I was asking for bitcoin, I heard about it in a video that you create UTXOs in bitcoin and was curious to know how it works.

Comment: Well, this forum is about Ethereum

Comment: Yes, sorry that was my mistake... Thanks for having your time